# How can we generate the go wrappers for the ink smart contracts?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I built one smart contract using ink!. I can make the contract's wasm and metadata files. Now, I need to create go bindings of my smart contract to find contract types and functions info in golang code. Do we have any command or script for that?

Comment: You mean auto-generated bindings for your contract? Or a library to create them manually?

Comment: Yes, auto generated bindings

Comment: There are currently no automatic contract bindings generators. Lets keep it unanswered, maybe there will be at one point.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is currently no way to auto-generate wrappers in Go.

A possible avenue to explore is to use https://github.com/727-Ventures/typechain-polkadot for generating TypeScript wrappers and then transpile them to Go code. I could imagine that a TypeScript2Golang exists somewhere.